# In Espresso can I detect if view contains text *or* other text

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a recycler view which should contain 3 items in an unknown order.

I know how to get a recycled item by position and how to check for text

```
onView(withId(...)).check(matches(atPosition(0, hasDescendant(withText(A)))));
```

But I don't know how I can say `withText(A)` ***or*** `withText(B)`

I googled but cant see anything like an OR hamcrest matcher

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Matchers.anyOf()`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/AnyOf.html). For example:

```
onView(anyOf(withText("X"), withText("Y"))).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Create your own custom `matcher`:

```
class MultiTextMatcher extends BoundedMatcher<View, TextView> {
    static MultiTextMatcher withTexts(String[] texts) {
        return new MultiTextMatcher(texts);
    }

    private final String[] texts;

    private MultiTextMatcher(String[] texts) {
       super(TextView.class);
       this.texts = texts;
    }

    @Override protected boolean matchesSafely(TextView item) {
       for(String text: texts) {
           if(item.getText().toString().equals(text)) {
               return true;
           }  
       }
       return false;
    }

    @Override public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("with texts:").appendValue(texts.toString());
    }
}
```

Then, just apply your custom `matcher` as follows:

```
onView(withId(...)).check(matches(atPosition(0, hasDescendant(withTexts({"A", "B"})))));
```

Comment: I really like this array syntax, but seeing as anyOf already exists, I'll use that. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, just another approach to answer your question, ;).